# Pyspark impute missing values in time series

Tags: pyspark, time-series, linear-regression, imputation

I am using Pyspark to analyse some time series data.

My data looks like this:

```
Key | time   | value
--------------------
 A  |   t0   |  null
 A  |   t1   |  1.5
 A  |   t2   |  1.7
 B  |   t3   |  0.5
 B  |   t4   |  null
 B  |   t5   |  1.1
 C  |   t6   |  4.3
 C  |   t7   |  3.4
 C  |   t8   |  null
 C  |   t9   |  2.7
```

It's safe to assume the relationship between "time" and "value" is approximately linear.

I want to interpolate the null values by training a linear regression from the remaining (time, value) datapoints for each key.

Eg. fit a regression on (t6, 4.3), (t7, 3.4), (t9, 2.7) to fill in the null value for t8.

Pandas has a df.interpolate() function, but I can't find anything similar for pyspark.

*Note, t0-t9 are irregular intervals.*

Comment: This is indeed not implemented function in pyspark. I think this blogpost by J. Walkenhorst gives you an idea how to do it.
You can use the window function to fill a spline between the missing data. See more here:
https://walkenho.github.io/interpolating-time-series-p2-spark/

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark Pandas does have interpolate now!!

```
>>> df = ps.DataFrame([(0.0, np.nan, -1.0, 1.0),
               (np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan),
               (2.0, 3.0, np.nan, 9.0),
               (np.nan, 4.0, -4.0, 16.0)],
              columns=list('abcd'))
>>> df
     a    b    c     d
0  0.0  NaN -1.0   1.0
1  NaN  2.0  NaN   NaN
2  2.0  3.0  NaN   9.0
3  NaN  4.0 -4.0  16.0

>>> df.interpolate(method='linear')
     a    b    c     d
0  0.0  NaN -1.0   1.0
1  1.0  2.0 -2.0   5.0
2  2.0  3.0 -3.0   9.0
3  2.0  4.0 -4.0  16.0
```

[interpolate docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

You can also consider using [imputer docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.Imputer.html)